# Deeplinking to Uber app fails setting location of pickup and drop off - Android

Tags: android, uber-api

this is initialization for Uber SDK :

```
SessionConfiguration config = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
                // mandatory
                .setClientId("xxx")
                // required for enhanced button features
                .setServerToken("xxx")
                // required for implicit grant authentication
                .setRedirectUri("http://www.wnna.co")
                // required scope for Ride Request Widget features
                .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS))
                // optional: set Sandbox as operating environment
                .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.SANDBOX)
                .build();

        UberSdk.initialize(config);
```

This is Uber Button to request a ride :

```
RideParameters rideParams = new RideParameters.Builder()
                    .setDropoffLocation(placeObject.getLat(), placeObject.getLng(), placeObject.getName(), placeObject.getFormatted_address())
                    .setPickupLocation(Global.loc.getLatitude(), Global.loc.getLongitude(), "WNNA", "")
                    .build();

            holder.requestButton.setRideParameters(rideParams);
```

I think my code should work fine but unfortunately when deeplinking to Uber app it only show me my location without dropping off point with navigation

aber app after deeplinking:

[image]

is there any missing steps or what ?

Comment: Can you clarify if the pickup, destination, or both pins are wrong in the user experience? Separately, please post the deeplink generated by the method so we can determine any problems you may be encountering.

Comment: @tsmith please look at my question, i've added output

Comment: Thanks, but I still need the deeplink itself, ie. "uber://?action=setPickup..." generated to help investigate. please provide that.

Comment: but i don't use it because in Uber doc doesn't say i have to use it with the button in order to deep linking @tsmith

Comment: You can retrieve the URI via two methods: 
1. In Intellij, please put a debug point in RequestDeeplink.java in the execute() method to discover the URI
2. In adb logcat, please look for the URI being used to launch uber.

Once we have this, we can help diagnose the bug or configuration issue.

Comment: facing the same issue, did you find the soution for this. I